# Git Repo Structure for Capistrano recipes and other Misc things

Tags: git, organization, code-organization, git-submodules

My problem is that I have a bunch of different capistrano recipes and code snippets that I use across multiple projects. My local file structure is a folder called helper-snibbits with folders under that called ./capistrano, ./php-bits, and .py-bits

I can track each snippet individually with a repo but that becomes hard to manage on the server and in my projects. I'd prefer to set up one repo with everything. What do you think is the best way to organize this? I love the submodule workflow but as I understand it would need a separate repo for each submodule. Is that true? If separate repos are the best way I'll end up doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being so late... :D

We recently released a tool for organizing capistrano configurations and recipes via a separate repository.

http://pulsar.nebulab.it

It's really useful if you have many projects and recipes to manage with capistrano and you want to reduce code duplication and generally live a better life.